# Linear subspace

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $$E=\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$$
>   $$F=\{ f\in E\mid f(x)= e^{3x}(a\cos(2x)+b\sin(2x)),\quad x\in \mathbb{R},a,b\in\mathbb{R} ) \}$$
>   Show that :
>   $F$ is  linear subspace of $E$

My attempts:

- Note that ( null maping  ) $f(x)=0=e^{3x}(0\cos(2x)+0\sin(2x))$ then $f=0\in F$ then $F \neq  \emptyset $
- Let $f,g \in F$ such as  $f(x)= e^{3x}(a\cos(2x)+b\sin(2x))$ and $g(x)=f(x)= e^{3x}(c\cos(2x)+d\sin(2x))$
  and let also  $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. our aime is to show that $\lambda f+ g\in F$ (since $F$ is functionnelle space )

Indeed,

\begin{align*}
k\times f(x)+g(x)&=k\times (e^{3x}(a\cos(2x)+b\sin(2x))+(e^{3x}c\cos(2x)+d\sin(2x))\\
&=e^{3x}((ka+c)\cos(2x)+(kb+d)\sin(2x)
\end{align*}

Since $(ka+c)$ et $(kb+d)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ then $k\times f+g \in F$

then  $F$ is well-Linear subspace of  $E$

1. Am i right? my solution is it well written

Comment: Yes, it's correct and what you wrote seems to be a good proof

Comment: my solution is it well written ?

Comment: Your solution is correct. I would say that a very straightforward way to show this is to say that $F$ is by definition the span of $e^{3x} \cos (2x), e^{3x} \sin (2x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your proof is well written.