# find a basis of F

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This question is related to that one [Linear subspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349075/linear-subspace?noredirect=1#comment2742796_1349075)

> Let $$E=\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$$
>   $$F=\{ f\in E\mid f(x)= e^{3x}(a\cos(2x)+b\sin(2x)),\quad x\in \mathbb{R},a,b\in\mathbb{R} ) \}$$
>
> Find a basis for $F$ and check its dimension ?

- \begin{align*}
  F&=\{ f\in E\mid f(x)= e^{3x}(a\cos(2x)+b\sin(2x)),\quad x\in \mathbb{R},a,b\in\mathbb{R} ) \}\\
  &=\{  e^{3x}a\cos(2x)+ e^{3x}b\sin(2x)),\quad x\in \mathbb{R},a,b\in\mathbb{R} ) \}\\
  &=\{  a\times e^{3x}\cos(2x)+ b\times e^{3x}\sin(2x),\quad x\in \mathbb{R},a,b\in\mathbb{R} ) \}\\
  &=Vect\{ f_1;f_2 \}\text{with }f_1(x)=e^{3x}\cos(2x) and f_2(x)=e^{3x}\sin(2x)\quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}
  \end{align*}
  then $\mathcal{B}=(e^{3x}\cos(2x);e^{3x}\sin(2x) )$ is Linear span of $F$
- linear independence property:

we looking for $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$  verify :

$$\alpha f_1 + \beta f_2=0_F$$

\begin{align*}
\alpha f_1(x)+\beta f_2(x)&=0_F\\
\alpha\times  e^{3x}\cos(2x) +\beta\times e^{3x}\sin(2x)&=0_{\mathbb{F}}  \quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R} \\
 e^{3x}\left(\alpha\times  \cos(2x) +\beta\times\sin(2x))\right)&=0_{\mathbb{F}}  \quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R} \\
\end{align*}

i tired to show $$\alpha f_1(x)+\beta f_2(x)=(\alpha - i\beta) e^{i(2x)}$$ 
to say $(\alpha - i\beta)=0_{\mathbb{F}}$ 
but no luck

i tired even this 
$$e^{i(2x)}=cos(2x)+i\sin(2x)$$
$$\alpha \cos(2x)+\beta \sin(2x)=(\alpha-i\beta ) e^{i(2x)}=(\alpha-i\beta ) (cos(2x)+i\sin(2x))=\alpha\cos(2x)+i\alpha\sin(2x)-i\beta\cos(2x)+\beta\sin(2x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

For linear independance, you can take two carefully chosen values of $x$.

Comment: i already tired that but no luck so no need to hints

Answer (score 1):

If you imagine that your $f_1$ and $f_2$ were linear dependent, that would mean that the function $x\mapsto e^{3x}(a\cos(2x)+b\sin(2x))$ is *identically* zero for some constants $a,b$ not both zero, and since $e^{3x}\neq0$ for all $x$, this would mean that $x\mapsto a\cos(2x)+b\sin(2x)$ is identically zero. It seems intuitively clear that the terms $a\cos(2x)$ and $b\sin(2x)$ can never precisely annihilate each other (if nonzero), since the functions sine and cosine are too different from each other for that. To show it rigorously, the easiest approach is to find some (linear) operation that will kill one term but not the other, and vice versa. For instance evaluating in $x=0$ kills the sine term but not the cosine, while evaluating in $x=\frac\pi4$ kills $\cos(2x)$ but not $\sin(2x)$. Formally, evaluating $a\cos(2x)+b\sin(2x)$ at $x=0$ gives $1a+0b=0$ so $a=0$, and similarly evaluating as $x=\frac\pi4$ gives $0a+1b=0$ so $b=0$.

You've got a lot other possibilities to argue. After the first evaluation at $x=0$,  you could instead of evaluating at $x=\frac\pi4$ evaluate *the derivative* at $x=0$ to conclude $b=0$, or you could reduce the given equation $a\cos(2x)+b\sin(2x)$ to $b\sin(2x)$ using the already found $a=0$, which implies $b\neq0$ using *any* value $x$ for which $\sin(2x)\neq0$.

Comment: but could you show $$\alpha f_1(x)+\beta f_2(x)=(\alpha - i\beta) e^{i(2x)}$$  to say $(\alpha - i\beta)=0_{\mathbb{F}}$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $af_1+bf_2=0$ for some coefficients $a,b$. We want to show that $a=b=0$ (so $f_1, f_2$ are linearly independent). Now
$$a=af_1(0) + bf_2(0) = 0$$
so we have $bf_2=0$. And now, $f_2(17) \neq 0$, so
$$bf_2(17)=0 \ \ \Rightarrow b=0$$